# calling previous fragment from another fragment inside navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Hi I have a navigation drawer and I have 4 fragments. I want to go from fragment 3 to fragment 2 on back press and on back press from fragment 4 it should go to fragment 1.How can I do this ??

I have tried adding fragments to back stack. If I add fragment to back stack when I click from home fragment the app should actually close.Instead of closing the fragment which I added to backstack is showing and when back pressing from that it showing the home fragment again and then the app is closing.

Comment: Hi, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and correct your question.

Answer (score 0):

//try this code add fragment number while opening new fragment and remove last positions from the list on backpress

```
public ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

public void addToStack(int pos)
{
    if (!list.contains(pos))
    {
        list.add(pos);
    }
}
```